# Use RegExp and split to read file text flash

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I have a file text more than 1 000 000 lines that begins by the character **C** and other one by **M**
Example:

```
C9203007870000000000000006339912610971240095400111200469300000 16122011AMI  00000100010000315       080  
C9203007870000000000000006339912610971240095400111200469300000 09122011B    590001000100000270016092100  
M920300787000000000000000633991261097124009540011120046930000031122011JVJF004       10     N
M920300787000000000000000633991261097124009540011120046930000009122011DEQP003       10     N                                
M920300787000000000000000633991261097124009540011120046930000012122011ACQK001       10Z    N
C9203007870000000000000006339912610971240095400111200469300000 24122011AMI  00000100010000315       080
C9203007870000000000000006339912610971240095400111200469300000 24122011AMI  00000100010000315       080
```

I want to put in my array only the lines who begins with the character **M**
How I can add in my split: var pattern:RegExp = /^M/;

```
var mFileReference:FileReference;
var mArray:Array = new Array();

function onFileLoaded(event:Event):void
{
    mFileReference = event.target as FileReference;
    data = mFileReference["data"];
    mArray = (data.toString()).split("\n");
}
```

I don’t want to pass by the loop ‘for’ its take a lot of time and resources
I want to add /^M/ to my split is it possible?

```
for each (var s:String in mArray) 
{
        if (pattern.test(s)) {
            values.push(s);
        }
}
```

Thanks everybody.

Answer (score 3):

Try this regular expression:

```
/^M.*/gm
```

This should match all lines that begin with M and nothing else.

It uses the `g` flag to match all cases of the expression in the string, and it uses `m` for multiline mode, so `^` and `$` will match the beginning/end of lines instead of the beginning/end of the string.

You can get get your array like this:

```
mArray = data.toString().match(/^M.*/gm);
```